# Prove a sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Show that the sequence $$p_n = n \sin\left(\frac 1 n\right)$$ converges to $1$ as $n$ goes to infinity. I am trying to use the epsilon delta definition of a limit to prove this. I know that $\sin(1/n)$ is bounded above by the function $1/n$. However, I cannot think of a lower bound for the function that will help to show convergence. Also, a step by step would be nice, to make sure I am writing my proof in the right form.

Comment: Have you seen an argument showing that $\sin(\theta)/\theta\to1$ as $\theta\to0$?

Comment: yes, however I want to show this by using functions that bound the sine function. An idea may be the series expansion for sine using the first two terms.

Comment: You just need the first term. Then show the rest do not matter. Or use the mean value theorem.

Comment: John; if you want to use the estimate you wrote in the other (deleted) question, you can do it this way: Using that estimate you have (for $x>0$),  $x-\frac{x^3}{6} \le \sin x \le x$, which gives, $1-\frac{x^2}{6} \le \frac{\sin x}{x} \le 1$, and so $|1-\frac{\sin x}{x}| \le \frac{x^2}{6}$. It is basically the same as my answer below.

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large\left\vert n\,\sin\left(1 \over n\right)\right\vert = \left\vert\cos\left(\xi\right)\right\vert}\quad$
where $\quad\displaystyle{\large 0 < \xi < {1 \over n}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $\lim_{x \to 0 } \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$. This follows from l'Hôpital's rule, or a Taylor series expansion.

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$, we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sin \frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$.

**Addendum**: To see the result using a series expansion:

The Taylor series for $\sin$ is $\sin x = x + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{2n+1} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$, hence for $x \neq 0$, we have
$\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{2n+1} \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$.

For $|x|< 1$, we have $|1-\frac{\sin x}{x}| \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty (|x|^2)^n \le \frac{|x|^2}{1-|x|^2}$.

If you take $|x|<\frac{1}{2}$, you get $|1-\frac{\sin x}{x}| \le 2 |x|^2 \le |x|$, from which the desired result follows.

Comment: could you do this without l'hopital? Possibly with the sine series expansion. I would gladly upvote

Comment: @johndoe: I did mention the Taylor series expansion - is that what you meant?

Comment: I learnt that you cannot use l'Hôpital in this particular case, because $\frac{d}{dt}\sin x = \cos x$ is derived from $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$. You will run into circular reasoning. Otherwise, this answer is fine.

Comment: @copper.hat yes exactly. Would you use that please?

Comment: Well, it depends on how you define $\sin$.

Comment: How about using sine is approximately x-(x^3)/6? Sine is bounded below, because the next term is using addition instead of subtraction.

Comment: That would be using the mean value theorem, which is fine too - you asked for the series expansion?

Answer (score 1):

We will use the fact that if $0\lt x\le 1$ then
$$x-\frac{x^3}{6}\lt \sin x\lt x.$$
Putting $x=1/n$, we find that 
$$1-\frac{1}{6n^2} \lt n\sin(1/n)\lt 1.\tag{1}$$
Now we can use Squeezing.

But if we want an $\epsilon$-$N$ proof of convergence, we continue as follows. From (1) we get
$$|n\sin(1/n)-1| \lt \frac{1}{6n^2}.$$
Now suppose that $\epsilon\gt 0$ us given. If $N$ the smallest  positive integer $\gt\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6\epsilon}}$ and $n\ge N$ then 
$$|n\sin(1/n)-1|\lt \epsilon.$$

Comment: Thank you! Bad keyboard, $s$ (and shift key) are unreliable.